# Table Field fixed column content(placeholder) for all entries

Tags: control-panel, table-field, table

I have a table field with 3 columns, one of them is 'Weekday', Type = single line text.

how can I set a **placeholder** to the weekday column ( Monday, Tuesday,....) in the **Control Panel**.

right now I have to set the value manually each time I create a new entry.

[image]

**Edit:**

I forgot to mention that I set default values but it's also not working .
[image]

Comment: Do the default value settings take effect if you create a new entry with that field? Changing default values for a field won't affect existing elements using that field.

Comment: Thank you, I deleted all the old entries and create new one's and all works great,
your comment is the right answer

Answer (score 1):

You can set default field values in Settings → Fields → *your table field*.

Scroll down on the page and you will see a **Default Values** section ([docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/table-fields.html#settings)).

Add the rows/values you need, save your field and next time you create an entry, the table will be prepopulated.

Comment: Actually, I did this step at first, but it seems not working.
the default values are not populated at all.
I'll update my question, Thank you